# Css3 MediaQueries, force @Media change on link

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a site using css3-mediaqueries.js for a mobile design. Works great but some users still prefer the "web-version". Is it possible to force the homepage through for example a link to not use the css than I have within:

@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

Maybe having a link at the top saying "Goto web-version"

Many thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to find a way to serve your page without the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to prevent the file from loading when a certain variable has been set.

This could be done by a lot of different ways, for example passing a variable in the $_GET on php systems. Or by using a cookie (php & javascript).

Comment: Thought of this but I see a big problem with users that have the .js or .css file cached. Dont you think?

Comment: True, then what about generating the file with php? Presenting an empty file when no mobile is desired.